# Using webpack-merge to prepend loaders to a rules `use` array

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-merge

I use [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge) to merge my webpack config files for dev and prod environments. To extract CSS in prod mode, I use the [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin). According to its documentation, I use it in place of the `style-loader`, which is only used during development. At this moment, my webpack config for CSS blocks looks like this:

```js
// webpack.common.js
{
  test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
  use: [
    process.env.NODE_ENV === `production` ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : `style-loader`,
    `css-loader`,
    `postcss-loader`,
    `sass-loader`
  ]
}
```

This works, but since I am using `webpack-merge`, I want to avoid this kind of logic in my common config file. Now, I have tried to split this up like so and have `webpack-merge` merge the various loaders:

```js
// webpack.common.js
{
  test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
  use: [
    `css-loader`,
    `postcss-loader`,
    `sass-loader`
  ]
}

// webpack.dev.js
{
  test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
  use: [
    `style-loader`,
    // webpack-merge should prepend all loaders from `webpack.common.js`
  ]
}

// webpack.prod.js
{
  test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
  use: [
    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    // webpack-merge should prepend all loaders from `webpack.common.js`
  ]
}
```

Using the basic `merge` fn, the `use` arrays doesnt get merged, but replaced, which ofc leads to an error: `ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

So I tried to use `merge.smartStrategy({ 'module.rules.use': 'prepend' })()`, but I get an error: `TypeError: this[MODULE_TYPE] is not a function`. Is there something I am missing or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a little update. In modern versions of webpack you should use mergeWithRules. In that case it looks like this

```
// webpack.common.js
{
  test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
  use: [
    `postcss-loader`,
    `sass-loader`
  ]
}

// webpack.dev.js
{
  test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
  use: [
    "style-loader"
  ]
}

mergeWithRules({
  module: {
    rules: {
      test: "match",
      use: "prepend",
    },
  },
})(common, dev);
```

Answer (score 5):

While splitting up my webpack config, I have forgotten to include the `MiniCssExtractPlugin` in the `plugins` section of my prod. config file.

Everything works as expected using `merge.smartStrategy({ 'module.rules.use': 'prepend' })()`.

Comment: from what I can tell, the [documentation](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge#customizearray-and-customizeobject) for merge has changed.  Can you provide an updated answer?